# Increase video cache size in Lineage 2

Tags: lineage-2

Is there any command line option to increase the video cache size to a greater value in Lineage II Goddess of Destruction Harmony client?  This would in turn allow me to have lesser lags and greater loading times.  I read in the official forums that there is an option to do exactly this by editing the `l2.ini` file but that would be altering the client so I want to know if there is another way around this problem...

Or altering `l2.ini` is the only option for doing this.

Comment: If you don't understand a question don't downvote it...

Comment: do you just want to speed it up to have better loading time? Are you sure that it's your PC that lags and not internet connection? What is your FPS? If it's low make sure that the vertical sync. is off and you don't use AA. Personally I don't see any difference between no AA and 16x AA(or whatever is max in Lineage 2)

Comment: @Novarg bigger cache will allow smoother gameplay in crowded places like Aden etc.. and for the record i am referring to the official servers not private.

Comment: Care to explain the downvote?

Comment: Would you mind sharing the solution you ended up using? Would really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Legally you can't edit the l2.ini (you can, if you are connected to a private server), it is against the EULA.

However, there exist other ways to increase your performance:

a) A solid-state drive (SSD) is much faster at random reads and writes than a hard disk drive (HDD). [Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ZHDz52FBX4)

b) If you have 16 GB or more RAM, try using a RAM disk.

Comment: L2 by default uses only 32MB of your graphics ram...  I have a 1GB DDR5 card and rest of the RAM goes to waste.  I am looking for a way to increase that.  It is possible I just don't know the switch to throw as command line argument.

Comment: Yes, it is a waste.  If you change l2.ini to 512mb (anything over 512mb is wasted) then it will increase the performance however you could be banned.

Comment: I find that hard to believe. If they didn't want you to change these settings they would've hardcoded them into the game, not provided an easy option to change them.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately "Lineage 2 is a very poorly coded game". I did experience lots of lags in crowded areas and even Alt+P barely helped. But when I was just killing mobs or PvPing(PKing once in a while) the game was running smooth.

I've found that topic, hope it will help you: http://boards.lineage2.com/archive/index.php/t-224450.html

What they say there:

- That's pretty normal in towns for L2 - blame all the player shops! As has been mentioned in other threads, the game isn't very optimized.
- get an SSD, in pc heavy locations your problem is your HD speed not your gfx card, that's where the lag comes from, loading all the models
- Lineage 2 is a very poorly coded game , sadly.

So basically there is no way to really increase the performance. Try using Alt+P(lowest details) when you are in Aden/Giran/any other crowded area

Comment: I found the solution without modifying the l2.ini :) .. had to dig into unreal engine stuff on which the game is based :)  Found a cleaner solution to the problem ... totally legit.

Comment: also game isn't poorly coded it uses unreal 2 engine :) which is a little old engine hence the glitches... Also when you turn Alt + P you are storing less graphics in your display cache :) thus the performance boost... with increased cache u won't need to hit that :)

Comment: @LoneWOLFs tell me more! How did you do it?

Comment: @LoneWOLFs If you have a solution, it's ok and *encouraged* here to post your own answer to your own question.

Comment: I would like to know how long it will take for someone to wirte a lineage2 unity3d client, given popularity of the game till now.